# A few questions about declaration semantics

Tags: c++, semantics

Which of these are more correct and more widely used? The actualy question is the last one, I think the behavior changes.

```
int *test; //for this, it is probably both?
int* test;


int& test;
int &test;
```

**Actual question:**

```
const int test;
int const test;


const int* test;
int* const test; //<-- I guess this also have a different meaning if I consider the last one?


const int& test;
int const& test; //also, considering last one, any difference?


const int*& test;
int* const& test; //<-- this is the correct one for stating "I won't modify the passed object, but I may modify the one pointed"? I have had problems with the other one sometimes, does the other one has some other meaning?
const int* const& test; //<-- another meaning?
```

Also I would be glad if you could point out if you know any visual *"ambiguations"* in this subject.

Comment: There *is* a valid question inside if you care to read. Stop proposing to close if you do not know the answer. Or if you do not care, ***do*** not care.

Comment: Look at [bjarne's faq](http://www.stroustrup.com/bs_faq2.html#whitespace) for the pointer one. **Edit**: [he talks about the placement of const too](http://www.stroustrup.com/bs_faq2.html#constplacement).

Comment: @JesseGood yes I have been reading that. No combination with references tough. I assume it is all caused by the pointer then. I will wait for answers though.

Comment: The reference issue is the same as the one for pointers, just remember C++ puts heavy emphasis on **types**, i.e. `int& i`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Where you place the space around `&` or `*` (or indeed if you have one or more spaces one or both sides) makes absolutely no difference. The placement of `const` does make a difference;

```
const int *test;
```

means that what `test` points to isn't being changed. So:

```
int b = 42;
*test = 42;
test = &b;
```

The `*test = 42;` would be illegal, but assigning test to a new address is valid.

```
int * const test;
```

means that `test` doesn't can't change it's value, but what it points to can:

```
int b = 42;
*test = 42;
test = &b;
```

now `test = &b;` is invalid.

```
const int& test;
int const& test; //also, considering last one, any difference?
```

Both the same. The const and int are the same side of `&`.

This one:

```
const int*& test;
```

means we have a reference to a `int *` where the value can't be changed. Perfectly valid, we can use the following:

```
test = &b;
```

these two:

```
int* const& test
const int* const& test;
```

is a reference to an `int *` and `const int *` respectively, and we can't change the pointer itself - so no point in passing it by reference.

Answer (score 2):

All of your examples give identical semantics for each line, apart from these:

```
//test is a pointer to a const int.
//test may be modified, but the int
//that it points to may not (through this
//access path).
const int* test;

//test is a const pointer to int.
//test may not be modified, but the
//int that it points to may.
int* const test;



//test is a reference to a pointer to a const int.
//The referenced pointer may be modified, but
//the int that that pointer points to may not be.
const int*& test;
//test is a reference to a const pointer to 
//int. The referenced pointer may not be modified
//but the int may be.
int* const& test; //<-- this is the correct one for stating
                  //    "I won't modify the passed object,
                  //     but I may modify the one pointed"?
                  //       Yes
                  //    I have had problems with the other one sometimes,
                  //    does the other one has some other meaning?
                  //       Yes
//test is a reference to a const pointer to const int.
//The referenced pointer may not be modified, nor may
//the int that it points to.
const int* const& test; //<-- another meaning?
```

Answer (score 1):

First, whitespace does not matter technically, except to the degree that it separates symbols.

That said, you won't get far trying to understand things by analyzing existing declarations.

You should start by *constructing* declarations.

And in those constructions, place `const` after whatever it applies to.

The general idea of C, unfortunately kept in C++, is that a declaration is like usage. So if, say, the expression `*p` should yield an `int`, then the declaration of `p` would be `int *p`. Now let's say that instead the expressions `*p` should yield an `int const`, then the declaration would be `int const *p`.

In C++ the emphasis is on types so a C++ programmer would likely write that as

```
int const* p;
```

separating the type thing from the name of whatever is declared.

But remember that the space doesn't matter *technically*.

And with this way of constructing declarations from the look of the intended usage, you can easily use a C++ compiler to *test* that your declaration works, that it compiles.

Comment: Does that mean p is a pointer to a const int, the pointed object may not be modified? It is different from "int* const p" right?

Answer (score 0):

`int *x` and `int &x` are considered being better. Why?
`int* x, y` can seem like two pointers to int, but this is one pointer and one int.
`int *x, *y` syntax is a bit better - you can see better that these are two pointers.

I know that I didn't cover second part of your question ;)

Comment: in C, yes, certainly. in C++ your preferred convention can't be applied universally and thus gives a hodgepodge of different-looking declarations. so instead, in C++, declare just 1 thing at a time.

Comment: Did it change since C?